# how to get sql to pring in the same row instead multple rows (db is db2)

Tags: sql, db2, row

I have 2 tables that I need to select data from.

table1:

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Mark |
| 3 | Anna |

table2:

| Person_ID | type | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | born | 1920 |
| 1 | graduated | 1950 |
| 1 | died | 2000 |
| 2 | born | 1940 |
| 2 | graduated | 1960 |
| 2 | died | 2011 |

I want to write a query that put them all into same row as:

| id | name | born | grad | died |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1920 | 1950 | 2000 |

I tried:

```
SELECT
    t1.id AS id, t1.name AS name, 
    CASE WHEN t2.type = 'born' THEN t2.year END AS born,
    CASE WHEN t2.type = 'graduated' THEN t2.year END AS grad,
    CASE WHEN t2.type = 'died' THEN t2.year END AS died
FROM
    table1 t1 
INNER JOIN 
    table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.Person_ID
WHERE
    t1.id = 1 
GROUP BY
    t1.id, t1.name, t2.type, t2.year
```

This is the result I get now:

| id | name | born | grad | died |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1920 | null | null |
| 1 | John | null | 1950 | null |
| 1 | John | null | null | 2000 |

Answer (score 1):

Use pivoting logic:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.type = 'born'      THEN t2.year END) AS born,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.type = 'graduated' THEN t2.year END) AS grad,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.type = 'died'      THEN t2.year END) AS died
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.Person_ID = t1.ID
GROUP BY
    t1.ID,
    t1.name
ORDER BY
    t1.ID;
```

Comment: before putting max it forced me to put year and type under the "group by" now when i pus max as you suggested I copuld remove it and it worked all together. Could you explain it please?

Comment: @Dexter Well `MAX()` is an aggregate function, so `type` and `year` can appear inside `MAX` without including them in `GROUP BY`.